# No puedo sacar un entero de archivo

Tags: c++

**Tema.h**

```
#ifndef TEMA_H
#define TEMA_H
#include <string>
#include <fstream>**
using namespace std;

typedef struct{
    string title;
    string intr;
    int seg;
}tTema;

bool cargar(tTema &tema);
void mostrar(tTema tema);
#endif
```

**Tema.cpp**

```
#include "Tema.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    tTema tema;
    cargar(tema);
}
bool cargar(tTema &tema){

    int num;
    bool ok = true;

    ifstream archivo;
    archivo.open("tema.txt");

    if (archivo.is_open()){
        archivo >> num;
        archivo >> tema.title;
        archivo >> tema.intr;
        archivo >> tema.seg;
    }
    else {
        ok = false;
    }
    return ok;
}
```

Sé que me falta terminar el codigo pero he probado muchas cosas y los "int seg" nunca me los coge. Los otros elementos de la estructura los coge bien, alguna idea?

El **txt** es así

```
5
Volvera
Dani Martin
120
```

Comment: Tanto las respuestas de @El Asiduo como de vangodp solucionan el problema (+1 a cada uno ;-) de la pregunta: "No puedo sacar un entero del archivo". Pero la verdad viendo el código de euridicegreyback pensé que la solución debería ser más fácil, debería bastar con usar el flag **std::skipws** dentro del flujo... pero resulta que no. Al menos a mi no me funcionaba. Y me pregunto ¿por qué? si precisamente vale para omitir los espacios en blanco, el operador >> de esta forma debería tomar como delimitador '\n', pero no lo hace ¿¿¿????

Comment: @euridicegreyback  Más allá del [link de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de responder.

Answer (score 4):

El problema que tienes está asociado al manejo de los `streams` de la librería estándar de `c++`.

Cuando quieres tomar el valor para `intr` en vez tomar "Dani Martin" toma "Dani", luego quieres poner un valor tipo `string` en un tipo `int`, si bien no da un error de ejecución, no obtienes el valor que deseado (ni en `intr`, ni en `seg`).

Podrías solucionar el tema utilizando [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/), pero tienes líneas en blanco que quieres ignorar y `getline` al contrario de `>>` no las ignora.

Un ejemplo de solución es el siguiente, es muy mejorable, pero es un comienzo.

**tema.h**

```
#ifndef TEMA_H
#define TEMA_H
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

typedef struct{
    std::string title;
    std::string intr;
    int seg;
}tTema;

bool cargar(tTema &tema);
void mostrar(tTema tema);
#endif
```

**tema.cpp**

```
#include "tema.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(){

    tTema tema;
    cargar(tema);
}
bool cargar(tTema &tema){

    int num;
    bool ok = true;

    std::ifstream archivo;
    archivo.open("tema.txt");

    //Variable auxiliar para saber linea con informacion es 
    int datosLeidos= 0;

    //Variable auxliar para leer las lineas del archivo
    std::string linea; 


    while (std::getline(archivo, linea)) {
      //Si la linea esta vacia, continua con la proxima
      if (linea.empty()) continue;

      std::stringstream is(linea);

      //Dependiendo de la linea leida
      //es la variable a la cual se asocia el valor  
      switch(datosLeidos) { 
        case 0:
          is >> num;
          break;
        case 1:
          is >> tema.title;
          break;
        case 2:
          //Necesitas tomar toda la linea
          getline(is, tema.intr);
          break;
        case 3:
          is >> tema.seg;
          break;
        default:
          std::cout << "Ya se leyeron 4 lineas. No hace nada.";
      }
      datosLeidos++;

    }
    //Si cargo los datos entonces esta ok.

    ok= (4 >= datosLeidos);

    //Para ver que hizo lo esperado 
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
    std::cout << tema.title << std::endl;
    std::cout << tema.intr << std::endl;
    std::cout << tema.seg << std::endl;

    return ok;
}
```

Si vas a hacer seguir haciendo cosas en `C++` con entrada/salida, te sugiero que mires las librerías de Boost sobre el tema ([Boost I/O](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/?view=category_IO)).

Referencias (en inglés):

[SO: Reading string with spaces in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476668/reading-string-with-spaces-in-c)

[stringstream en cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)

Answer (score 2):

El problema del operador **>>** es que lee hasta encontrar un espacio(**' '**), un tabulador(**'\t'**) o un salto de linea(**'\n'**). Si tienes la frase **"Dani Martin"** y lo intentas leer con **archivo >> tema.intr**, intr va a contener solamente **"Dani"**, dejando "Martin" para la siguiente lectura, que ademas esperas leer un **int** por ultimo, por esa razón no te sale bien.

Para leer algo como eso en el archivo:

> 5
>   Volvera
>   Dani Martin
>   120

Necesitas eso:

//...

```
string firstName, secondName;

ifstream archivo;
archivo.open("tema.txt");

if ( archivo.is_open() ){
    archivo >> num; // Leer el primer int
    archivo >> tema.title; //Leer a "Volvera"
    archivo >> firstName >> secondName; //firstName="Dani" y secondName="Martin"

    tema.intr = firstName + " " + secondName ; // Unimos el primer nombre con el segundo y lo asignamos a tema.intr

    archivo >> tema.seg; //Leemos el ultimo int

    archivo.close(); // Importante cerrar antes de salir

    //imprimimos los resultados para ver si todo va ok.
    cout << tema.title << endl;
    cout << tema.intr << endl;
    cout << tema.seg << endl;
    //resto del programa...
```

Creo que eso es lo que buscas. Saludos.